# LogSpace reductions vs. PTime reductons for defining PSpace-completeness

Tags: reductions, pspace

Continuing https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90527/is-every-pspace-complete-problem-complete-with-respect-to-logspace-reductions : earlier, PSPACE-completeness was defined via logspace reductions (e.g., cf. http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/LowerBounds.pdf), whereas it is defined via ptime reductions nowadays (e.g., cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE).

Why has it changed? Is it just because the folks after Dexter Kozen got too lazy even to **say** that one can go the extra mile to show that their reductions are actually logspace, let alone actually going that extra mile? Or is there a deeper, technical reason?

Crosspost: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115921/logspace-reductions-vs-ptime-reductons-for-defining-pspace-completeness

Comment: It’s not *earlier* vs. *nowadays*. It’s just that different works use different conventions. In particular, for an introductory text such as a Wikipedia article there is an incentive to use the most simple definitions, whereas in a research paper there is an incentive to use definitions that make the results as strong as possible.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am not aware of *recent* publications in which PSPACE-completeness is defined via logspace reductions. E.g., "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Sipser (3rd ed.) and "Introduction to automata theory, languages, and computation" by Hopcroft/Motwani/Ullman, 2001 use polytime reductions.

Comment: A couple of examples of considering logspace reductions (1) https://doi.org/10.1007/s00037-016-0124-0 (2)
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-29026-9_18 (3) https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-00250-3_5

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Good to know. Thank you! I was surprised to discover that reductions for PSPACE exist that I was not aware of earlier (e.g., ZPP reductions). What would be the best source to catch up?